# Use -like variable in powershell if statement

Tags: powershell

Is it possible to use -like and wildcard search in a PowerShell if statement - i'm trying to do something like this;

```
    $name = 'matt'
$current = 'matt@'

if ($name -like "*$current*"){
    write-host("this name matches")
}
```

However the "*$current*" does not work - please advise?

Comment: Is the `@` in `$current = 'matt@'` a typo?  If not, then things aren't going to match as you've written them, since `$current` is not a part of `$name` (though it looks like there is some overlap).  If you swap `$name` and `$current` it will work since `$name` _is_ a part of `$current`: `$current -like "*$name*"`.  It might be helpful to clarify the exact problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: @boxdog that works perfectly, thanks, knew it would be a simple one. Cheers :)

Comment: I don't see why `matt -like *matt@*` would work.

Comment: @boxdog the problem i'm trying to solve is to write an out put of user email addresses which I have which do not match with any proxyAddresses in AD. -notlike currently doesn't seem to work when i'm putting the variable output of get-aduser - property proxyaddresses in

Answer (score 2):

The other way around works...

```
$name = 'matt@'
$searchkey = 'matt'

if ($name -like "*$searchkey*"){
    write-output "this name matches"
}
```